# Stacking conditional navigator buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I am trying to create a conditional menu list for a sliding menu. So far, I've gotten the functionality to work, as far as showing different menu items for different types of users. But my only issue now is, in the menu, these two items "Messages" and Settings" are showing up side by side of each other. I've tried to move the second Icon row outside of the row brackets and so on. I just can't figure it out. These brackets are already confusing as is, for me. Can someone look at this and help me get the Settings Icon to do under Messages?

I've included the complete method snippet so everyone can have an idea of what I'm trying to do. This was the only way I knew how to do it where I can make my menu conditional.

```
customSlideMenu() {
    Function onTap;
    bool ownProfile = currentOnlineUserId == widget.userProfileId;
    if(ownProfile) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.blue,
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            height: 40,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.mail),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Messages",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.settings),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Settings",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.blue,
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            height: 40,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.mail),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Message",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.block),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Block",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Row widget align its children right next to each other. Try using the Column widget to achieve stacking two children on top of each other

```dart
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.mail),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Messages",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.settings),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Settings",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Okay so I tried that, and it worked, getting them to stack on top of each other! But now the only thing is, the text is stacking under the icons too. How would I be able to keep the text next to it's respective icon?

Comment: @Indigo I just updated the code. I wrapped each icon and text with a Row widget do that the Row widget containing the Icon and text is the widget being stacked on each other. Please mark as answer if that was helpful

Comment: Thank you so much it was super helpful. Now that I have the design aspect of it complete, I'm going to try and get the onTap navigation functionality working for these conditional buttons. If I can't figure it out, would you mind if I picked your brain figuring that out?

Comment: sure, just open another question and tag me with the link to the question whenever you need help

Comment: do you think you could help me with this one? @ByteMe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895099/flutter-unhandled-exception-nosuchmethoderror-the-getter-id-was-called-on-n