# Flutter Provider update user data in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I'm trying to refactor my code to reduce Firebase read operations. For this I'm using Sharedpreferences. The code is structured in such a way that there's a provider that take's care of the update process and saves the new values in shared preferences. Here is the code.

```
submit() async {
    final User user = _auth.currentUser;
    DocumentReference ref =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


    try {
      if (_image != null){

        mediaurl= await uploadImage();

        await ref.update({"MediaURL": mediaurl});
        prefs.setString("MediaURL", mediaurl);

      }
      if(username!=null){
        ref.update({"username":userNamecontroller.text});
        prefs.setString('username', username);
      }
      if(description!=null){
        ref.update({"description":descriptionController.text});
        prefs.setString('description', description);
      }

    } catch (e) {print("tHE ERROR IS $e");}
    notifyListeners();

  }
```

The problem however is the submit function does not work. No data is updated to firebase and the error from my catch block is

```
tHE ERROR IS NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'absolute' was called on null.
```

Any ideas what this 'absolute' is?

Comment: Did you check if its related to the function `uploadImage` ? try to comment it and run the function, and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, Can you check if this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62899331/15774177) helps you?